# Passing a Django Form Class variable to the nested class Meta, how?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

G'day there. I've currently got a bit of an annoyance more than anything. The code below works fully, as expected. Basically it's a ModelForm that dynamically bases it's model on a string received in the url, or based on the class of an instance if that's provided.

My question is whether it's possible to abstract this out into another module, forms.py, by passing the model_name variable. I can pass model_name to the form Class no problems, but I can't figure out how to pass it to Meta after that. Is there any easy way to do this? If not this'll do, but it would make my view code heaps neater.

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_staff, login_url="%slogin/" % NINJA_ADMIN_URL_PREFIX)
def content_form(request, model_name=None, edit=False, call_name=''):
    if edit:
        content = Content.objects.get(call_name=call_name)
        model_name = content.fields.__class__.__name__

    class ContentForm(forms.ModelForm):
        parent = ModelTextField(queryset=Content.objects.all(), widget=JQueryAutocomplete(
                        source_url='%sjson/call_names.json' % NINJA_ADMIN_URL_PREFIX, jquery_opts = {'minLength': 2},
                        override_label='item.fields.call_name', override_value='item.fields.call_name'),
                        required=False)

        class Meta():
            model = get_ninja_type(model_name)
            widgets = {
                    'ninja_type': forms.widgets.HiddenInput(),
                }

        def clean_parent(self):
            call_name = self.cleaned_data['parent']
            if call_name:
                try:
                    parent = Content.objects.get(call_name=call_name)
                except Content.DoesNotExist:
                    raise forms.ValidationError("The call name '%s' doesn't exist. Choose another parent." % call_name)
                return parent
            else:
                return None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if edit:
            form = ContentForm(request.POST, instance=content.fields)
        else:
            form = ContentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            content = form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Your new content has been saved.")
            return HttpResponseRedirect('%scontent/' % NINJA_ADMIN_URL_PREFIX)

    else:
        if edit:
            form = ContentForm(instance=content.fields)
        else:
            form = ContentForm(initial={'ninja_type': model_name.lower(),
                                    'author': request.user})
    if edit:
        page_title = 'Edit %s' % model_name
    else:
        page_title = 'Create New %s' % model_name

    return render(request, 'ninja/admin/content_form.html', {
                  'form': form,
                  'ninja_type': model_name,
                  'page_title': page_title,
                  'edit': edit,
                  'meta_field_names': NINJA_META_FIELD_NAMES,
                  })
```

Comment: I had a thought, maybe the form could be wrapped in a function that returns a class, and then call that function. Will try that when I get a chance.

Comment: Yep, a function that returns a class works fine. I'll post the source of the answer once the site lets me. (too low a reputation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was pretty obvious when I thought about it. A function returning a class works fine. This is what's left at the start of views.py. I'm thinking this is likely the best way to do this, or at least the most concise.

```
@user_passes_test(lambda u: u.is_staff, login_url="%slogin/" % NINJA_ADMIN_URL_PREFIX)
def content_form(request, model_name=None, edit=False, call_name=''):
    if edit:
        content = Content.objects.get(call_name=call_name)
        model_name = content.fields.__class__.__name__

    ContentForm = get_content_form(model_name)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if edit:
            form = ContentForm(request.POST, instance=content.fields)
        else:
```

This is the forms.py entry.

```
def get_content_form(model_name):
    class DynamicContentForm(forms.ModelForm):
        parent = ModelTextField(queryset=Content.objects.all(), widget=JQueryAutocomplete(
                        source_url='%sjson/call_names.json' % NINJA_ADMIN_URL_PREFIX, jquery_opts = {'minLength': 2},
                        override_label='item.fields.call_name', override_value='item.fields.call_name'),
                        required=False)

        class Meta():
            model = get_ninja_type(model_name)
            widgets = {
                    'ninja_type': forms.widgets.HiddenInput(),
                }

        def clean_parent(self):
            call_name = self.cleaned_data['parent']
            if call_name:
                try:
                    parent = Content.objects.get(call_name=call_name)
                except Content.DoesNotExist:
                    raise forms.ValidationError("The call name '%s' doesn't exist. Choose another parent." % call_name)
                return parent
            else:
                return None
    return DynamicContentForm
```